# How to add Go support to Geany

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, go, geany

I am trying to make syntax hightlighting and building options work for Geany, any advice?

Comment: For my fellow Windows programmers, there is a silly trick to getting this to work: `filetypes.go.conf` must actually be named `filetypes.Go.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in $GOROOT/misc and http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/ for syntax files from other editors to get an idea.

Barring that, start with C or C++ and add/substract things like `go`, `<-`, `func`, etc.

Comment: I started with C and nothing works :( I've created a ~/.config/geany/filetypes.go based on the C one provided and get no hightlighting at all.

Answer (score 8):

I just noticed this page: http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/geany/

Seems like they've got everything you need right there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [Geany formatting Instructions posted by Steve Horsley to golang-nuts:](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/geany/)

1. In Geany, goto Tools->Configuration Files->filetype_extensions.conf and add in the following new heading:

   ```
   Go=*.go;
   ```
2. Copy the C definition filetypes.c to filedefs/filetypes.Go.conf:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/geany/filetypes.c ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Go.conf
   ```
3. Edit filetypes.Go.conf and change the setting and keywords sections to this:

   ```
   [settings]
   # default extension used when saving files
   extension=go
   lexer_filetype=C

   [keywords]
   # all items must be in one line
   primary=break case chan const continue default defer else fallthrough for func go goto if import interface map package range return select struct switch type var
   secondary=byte int int8 int16 int32 int64 uint uint8 uint16 uint32 uint64 float32 float64 complex64 complex128 uintptr string
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the Go filetype in ~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf ?

```
[Extensions]
...
Go=*.go
...
```

if the conf file doesn't yet exist, copy it from /usr/share/geany and add that line under 'Extensions' (or look for it under Tools > Configuration Files).

Answer (score 1):

I made a Python script that automates the directions in the link provided by Jaybill McCarthy.

```
import shutil, re, os

HOME = os.environ['HOME']

shutil.copy('/usr/share/geany/filetype_extensions.conf', HOME +'/.config/geany/')
with open(HOME + '/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf', 'r') as f:
    fileData = f.read()
fileData = re.sub(r'Haskell=.*;', r'Go=*.go;\nHaskell=*.hs;*.lhs;', fileData)
fileData = re.compile('(\[Groups\][^\[]Programming=.*?$)', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE).sub(r'\1Go;', fileData)
with open(HOME + '/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fileData)


textSettings = """[settings]
extension=go
lexer_filetype=C
comment_single=//
comment_open=/*
comment_close=*/
comment_use_indent=true
"""
textKeywords = """[keywords]
primary=break case chan const continue default defer else fallthrough for func go goto if import interface map package range return select struct switch type var
secondary=byte int int8 int16 int32 int64 uint uint8 uint16 uint32 uint64 float32 float64 complex64 complex128 uintptr string"""

shutil.copy('/usr/share/geany/filetypes.c', HOME + '/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Go.conf')
with open(HOME + '/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Go.conf', 'r') as f:
    fileData = f.read()
fileData = re.compile(r'\[settings\].*?^\[', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE).sub('%s\n\n[' %textSettings, fileData)
fileData = re.compile(r'\[keywords\].*?^\[', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE).sub('%s\n\n[' %textKeywords, fileData)
with open(HOME + '/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Go.conf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fileData)

print "Complete!"
```

I'm not sure if this means I am lazy, or the other way around... o.O.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have this on as a gist?